# Reverse for 'listas' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'name': 'Lucas Henrique Paes'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['alunos/$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Reverse for 'listas' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'name': 'Lucas Henrique Paes'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['alunos/$']

urls.py

```
> urlpatterns = [   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>   url(r'^$','escola.views.home', name='inicio'),
>   url(r'^alunos/$','escola.views.escola', name='listas'),
>   url(r'^alunos_criar/','escola.views.create', name='criar'),
>   url(r'^escola/(P<pk>\d+)/$','escola.views.escola_update',name='escola_update'), ]
```

models.py

```
    def __str__(self):
          return '{} {}º{}'.format(self.nome, self.série, self.turma)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('listas', kwargs={'name':self.nome})
```

criar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Novo Aluno</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Create Post' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = EscolaForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "criar.html", context)
```

Comment: `listas` url does not accept any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another URL for your DetailView:

```
url(r'^alunos/(?P<slug>[\.\w-]+)/$',AlunoDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Change the get_absolute_url implementation to use this new url:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'name':slugify(self.nome)})
```

Note that you have to use a slug unless you are sure that the name is usable in a URL. (For more slugify functionality, there is awesome-slugify: https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify)